# Get window height with absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement infinite scroll in my web page but because of absolute positioning window scroll event is not getting triggered.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: When you use absolute position (in the body I guess?) you should use the scroll event on the element with overflow scroll/auto. But without further information we can't help you.